# Why does undo remove history in Solidworks?

Tags: undo, solidworks

I started using Solidworks recently. After drawing many things, pressing Ctrl+Z undoes changes one by one, but removes the history so that I can not redo after I exit from a sketch while undoing.

Which means, undo can easily make me lose my drawings. Is there any setting to prevent this, or nobody cares about this problem?